# Couchbaselite - Is it possible not to create revision document for standalone application

Tags: react-native, couchbase, couchbase-lite

I am building a "standalone" mobile app with ReactNative and CouchbaseLite using the library react-native-couchbase-lite.

Is it possible to have only one document(ie only the original document) without any revision document even though if i update the document multiple times. For example if i make multiple update to a ToDo task, only the original document should be updated and no extra revision document should be created.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  You can tune the maxRevTreeDepth parameter.  Set it via a Database object instance.  It defaults to 20.

Edit: An alternative approach might be to create a new document every time, and delete the old one.  This would be appropriate in a case where one wants to save only a single revision of some documents.  It would require creating a new document ID each time, too.

Comment: maxRevTreeDepth needs to be set to '0' or '1' to have only the original document and without any revision documents?

Comment: Yes, 0 I believe.  This means you lose all conflict resolution capabilities, because without the revision history you can't track the lineage of a document.

Comment: As indicated above, it is undesirable to set the maxRevTreeDepth to a low value. You will end up with a bunch of "disconnected trees" and will lose conflict resolution capabilities. You can read more about it [here](https://blog.couchbase.com/database-sizes-and-conflict-resolution/) - specifically the section on "Configuration of the max depth of the Revision Tree"